# dictionary comprehension to append variable length lists

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I’m looking for the pythonic way to create a dictionary of lists where you append values to a list for a series of keys.  So a dictionary `n` which stores the sum of digits for the values up to 1000, with the sum of the digits the key, for example:

```
n[25] = [799, 889, 898, 979, 988, 997]
```

Using a basic list comprehension doesn't work as it overwrites smaller values and only allows one, the largest, value per key,

```
n = {sumdigits(i): i for i in range(1000)}
```

I've got a two line working version below, but I am curious whether there is a neat one line solution to create a dictionary of variable length lists.

```
def sumdigits(x):
  return sum(int(i) for i in str(x))

n = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(1000):  
  n[sumdigits(i)].append(i)
```

Comment: IMO there is no more pythonic way than what you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a possibility that is one line (as you don't count the defaultdict initialization in your 2-line solution). With the advantage that it is significantly faster than the other solutions.

```
n = defaultdict(list)
{n[sum(int(d) for d in str(nb))].append(nb) for nb in range(1000)}
```

or really in one line (using the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) python3.8 +)

```
{n := collections.defaultdict(list)[sum(int(i) for i in str(x))].append(x) for x in range(NB)}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you already have is very pythonic. There's absolutely nothing wrong with it and crucially it's clear what's happening.

If you really want a one line solution, I think you need 2 loops. One loop for values of `n`, which can be anything from 1 to 27 (`sumdigits(999)`). Then another loop to go over the items in the range 1-1000.

Here's what that would look like, but it's very inefficient from a time complexity view. What you have has time complexity O(n) which is good. But doing it in a comprehension has complexity
O(n^sumdigits(n-1)). Because for every key you have to iterate over the entire range 1-1000, but most of those are discarded.

```
{n: [i for i in range(1000) if sumdigits(i) == n] for n in range(sumdigits(999) + 1)}
```

Comment: I just couldnt see a way around create a variable length list and so thank you for showing me the method, even though in the end the one line version is very inefficient.  Will stick with original.

Comment: Nice to see a complexity analysis. for n growing you can even simplify it to O(n*log(n)) since sumdigits(n-1) = 9/log(10)*log(n) for n a power of 10.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be this, but wasn't totally confident about my log laws.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a one-line solution, you can do the following combining list and dict comprehension:

```
dct = {sumdigits(i): [j for j in range(1000) if sumdigits(i)==sumdigits(j)] for i in range(1000)}
```

That said, I do not think that it gets more pythonic than the simple `for` loop you've suggested yourself and I think you should stick to that due to performance reasons as well.

Comment: Not to criticize the answer, just as a hint for anyone considering using it: This is vastly more inefficient because it iterates over all numbers in `range(1000)` many times instead of just once.

Comment: Thank you.  That is a solution and clever way to answer my question.  However, sometimes maybe you can make things too complex :-).